# IE Does not load my Google Font

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I just Copy and pasted my Google font import and code straight from the google code

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
```

are the **EXACT** code i used

WORKS IN chrome and Firefox and Opra !just ie does not want to work.

Comment: Have you looked at the network profile in development tool, to check that if the file is loaded?

Comment: all version of IE does not load the font. @vico yes it is loaded

Comment: I've just tried to use it on my local machine and it works fine in all IEs (even IE7). Post your css rules where you assign the font to element please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be a Font file support issue 
**http://caniuse.com/woff**

Seems like you might have set the IE meta tag for compatibility

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Read here for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528(v=vs.85).aspx

Because your IE is rendering with ie 8 or 7 depending on your code, it no longer supports the font formats that google font returns

Here is a return body content when calling import

[image]

Comment: IE does not use .woff format. Also it provides the .eot format that is supported by older IEs.

Comment: @easwee but seems like google font is returning their files in woff format which is why it is causing problems i guess. (sorry i cropped off the file extension at the end.. but they were in **woff** that is why I assumed it

Comment: Thanks! There was that meta tag, now I removed and it is loading!

Comment: @vico Yeah just checked - there's double format specified - embeded open type for old ie and woff for new ie. Nice catch.